# Test cases in Jasmine. Is it possible to run the same test on multiple different data sets?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I would like to run a Jasmine tests multiple times using different test data and when any test fails that specific test case should be easily identifiable.

In the NUnit testing framework this is can achievable with the TestCase attribute.

I have tried putting the it block inside of a foreach block and while the tests show, they do not run, as can be seen here:

[image]

Below is the implementation I have tried:

```
/// <reference path="../Jasmine/jasmine.js"/>
/// <reference path="../Jasmine/jasmine-html.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Site/wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Site/wwwroot/js/nlHoldem.js"/>

describe("nlHoldem.js", function () {
    var mockHtml;

    var deckOfCards = [
        { id: 'ace-of-spades' },
        { id: 'king-of-spades' }
    ];

    beforeEach(function () {
        mockHtml = getMockHtml();
        $(document.body).append(mockHtml);
        nlHoldem.init();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $('#mock-html-container').remove();
        sessionStorage.clear();
    });

    deckOfCards.forEach(function (card) {
        it("should add styling of top -5px to "+ card.id +" on mouseover", function () {
            // Arrange
            var targetCard = $("#" + card.id);

            // Act
            targetCard.mouseover();


            // Assert
            expect(targetCard.css("top")).toBe("-5px");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your Imgur pic is not viewable.  That said I think the issue here is that you wrapped your it block in another function which is never invoked.  Just a guess but what happens if you move the deckOfCards.forEach to within the it block?  Will they run then?

Comment: @ruby_newbie Thanks for the quick response. Moving the the foreach to within the it block runs the tests. However, doing so means that I am not able to dynamically generate the test name and therefore I do not know which specific test case fails when one does fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly I think what you are trying to do is ill advised but I think this could possibly work if you do this: `deckOfCards.forEach(function (card) {
        it("should add styling of top -5px to "+ card.id +" on mouseover", function () {
            // Arrange
            var targetCard = $("#" + card.id);

            // Act
            targetCard.mouseover();


            // Assert
            expect(targetCard.css("top")).toBe("-5px");
        });
    })();`   Notice the function invocation at the end of the for each block.  Again I do not advise this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show which specific test case failed in the for loop (inside of the it block as @ruby_newbie suggested), you can add a custom failure message like so:

```
it("should add styling of top -5px to card on mouseover", function () {
    deckOfCards.forEach(function(card) {
        // Arrange
        var targetCard = $("#" + card.id);

        // Act
        targetCard.mouseover();


        // Assert
        expect(targetCard.css("top")).toBe("-5px", "failed on: " + card.id);
    });
});
```